# Can we implement a different function body in a class for when the function is called from an anonymous object?

Tags: c++, class

I implemented an example class Demo, with an overloaded function run. The function run has a different implementation depending on whether it is called from an immutable instance of an object or a mutable instance. Is it also possible to create yet another version of run that runs when we call it from an anonymous function? i.e.,

```
Demo().run;
```

Here is the code so far.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Demo {
  public:
   Demo() { }

   void run() { cout << "Called from object or from function expecting a reference to object" << '\n'; }
   const void run() const { cout << "Called from const object" << '\n'; }
 };

int main(){
    const Demo obt;
    Demo obt2;
    obt2.run();
    obt.run();
    Demo().run();
}
```

The output is

```
Called from object or from function expecting a reference to object
Called from const object
Called from object or from function expecting a reference to object
```

so right now the Demo().run() sees the temporary anonymous class Demo() as a normal class.

Comment: note that `const void` is a bit misleading, since you cannot have different overloads based on just return type anyway

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Good call. Out of curiosity, why don't you just close it as a duplicate?

Comment: Judgement call. I'm only about 99% sure that it's a duplicate.

Comment: From what I see the possible duplicate, provides the solution to the problem here.